# How do you handle shrinking or growing nodes in xml data structures?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm very new to XSLT but have some programming experience. I'm finding how XSL works pretty weird sometimes, but enjoying the challenge. At

this stage I just need some advice to point me in the right direction so I can research for myself and the problem I'm describing hasn't even

occurred yet, but I'm sure it will when we go from 'testing' to 'live' so I will need to know how to handle it. At the moment I'm hard coding

indexs to get the values and this works fine for nodes I know that won't change, but some surely will so I need an alternative to my bodgy

hardcoding.

Also, I tried to use global variables for my repetitive '"' and ', ' code below to make code easier to read but they kept coming up out

of scope (so they were local?). Couldn't see what I was doing wrong, or where to declare them. Ideally I want to do it at the begining of the

script and be able to call them whenever and wherever I want but this is not urgent.

For example, at the moment I'm **using this;**

```
<!-- AHPRA XML CSV Converter Script -->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" media-type="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:param name="component"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>

    <!-- COMPONENT 4 communications -->
    <!-- contactID, mediumCode, areaCode, communicationDetails -->
    <xsl:when test="$component=4">
      <xsl:for-each select="//person">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(concat(
          communications/communication/mediumCode, 
          communications/communication/areaCode, 
          communications/communication/communicationDetails))!=0">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(
          '&quot;', contactID, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
          communications/communication[1]/mediumCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
          communications/communication[1]/areaCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
          communications/communication[1]/communicationDetails, '&quot;', '&#xa;', 
          '&quot;', contactID, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
          communications/communication[2]/mediumCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
          communications/communication[2]/areaCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
          communications/communication[2]/communicationDetails, '&quot;', '&#xa;', 
          '&quot;', contactID, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
          communications/communication[3]/mediumCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
          communications/communication[3]/areaCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
          communications/communication[3]/communicationDetails, '&quot;', '&#xa;')" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>

    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**On this;**

```
<medicare>  
  ...
  <person>
    <contactID>5290001890</contactID>
    <communications>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>T</mediumCode>
      <areaCode>02</areaCode>
        <communicationDetails>92881781</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>E</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>rabina.smiley@ekit.com</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    <communication>
        <mediumCode>M</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>04290012333</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    </communications>
  </person>
  <person>
    <contactID>4400139361</contactID>
    <communications>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>T</mediumCode>
      <areaCode>07</areaCode>
        <communicationDetails>49281771</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>E</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>suzanne.jones2@optus.com</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    <communication>
        <mediumCode>M</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>0404009266</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    </communications>
  </person>
  ...
</medicare>
```

**To get this;**

```
contactID,mediumCode,areaCode,communicationDetails
"5290001890", "T", "02", "92881781"
"5290001890", "E", "", "rabina.smiley@ekit.com"
"5290001890", "M", "", "04290012333"
"4400139361", "T", "07", "49281771"
"4400139361", "E", "", "suzanne.jones2@optus.com"
"4400139361", "M", "", "0404009266"
```

But I'm worried this will not work if my daily xml file changes **to this;**

```
<medicare>  
  ...
  <person>
    <contactID>5290001890</contactID>
    <communications>
       <communication>
        <mediumCode>E</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>rabina.smiley@ekit.com</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    <communication>
        <mediumCode>M</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>04290012333</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    </communications>
  </person>
  <person>
    <contactID>4400139361</contactID>
    <communications>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>T</mediumCode>
      <areaCode>07</areaCode>
        <communicationDetails>49281771</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>E</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>suzanne.jones2@optus.com</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    <communication>
        <mediumCode>M</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>0404009266</communicationDetails>
    </communications>
  </person>
  ...
</medicare>
```

**Or this;**

```
<medicare>  
  ...
  <person>
    <contactID>5290001890</contactID>
    <communications>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>T</mediumCode>
    <areaCode>02</areaCode>
        <communicationDetails>92881781</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>E</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>rabina.smiley@ekit.com</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    <communication>
        <mediumCode>M</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>04290012333</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>X</mediumCode>
    <areaCode>XX</areaCode>
        <communicationDetails>XXXX</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    </communications>
  </person>
  <person>
    <contactID>4400139361</contactID>
    <communications>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>T</mediumCode>
      <areaCode>07</areaCode>
        <communicationDetails>49281771</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>E</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>suzanne.jones2@optus.com</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    <communication>
        <mediumCode>M</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>0404009266</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    </communications>
  </person>
  ...
</medicare>
```

Comment: so your worried the ammount of communication nodes may change in length? luckily there are several ways around this

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that uses some of the most fundamental and powerful features of XSLT: templates, template matching and the XSLT processing model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the push style so its only applying the template to the nodes which exsist!
you will find once you get to grips with xslt its very powerful!

```
<!-- AHPRA XML CSV Converter Script -->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" media-type="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:param name="component"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>

    <!-- COMPONENT 4 communications -->
    <!-- contactID, mediumCode, areaCode, communicationDetails -->
    <xsl:when test="$component=4">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//person/communications/communication" />
    </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="person/communications/communication">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(
          '&quot;', ../../contactID, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
          mediumCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
          areaCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
          communicationDetails, '&quot;', '&#xa;')"/>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What @Dimitre failed to explain was that this will output all communication elements, even if they have none of the required fields. You need to add an additional predicate to the template match attribute to select only those with text to output. I suggest `[string-length(concat(mediumCode, areaCode, communicationDetails))!=0]`. @Dimitre's answer is incorrect, as it would include communication elements that have none of these three child elements, but do have others containing text.

Comment: What @Flynn1179 pretends to have failed to see is that I am providing the simplest and shortest answer that *on the provided XML document* produces the wanted result. For any given solution one can modify the provided document in a way that the solution would no-longer produce the wanted result. @Flynn also didn't mention that if there was power outage while performing the transformation, it wouldn't produce the wanted result -- therefore it is incorrect.

Comment: No, the 'simplest and shortest' answer would be to leave off the `[string-length() > 0]` altogether (based on the provided XML). Based on your argument, @Treemonkey's answer is missing nothing. However, if that's not what you were claiming was 'missed', please elaborate; claiming there's an error/omission on a answer without pointing out where helps no-one.

Comment: @Flynn1179: What is missed is obvious -- an `<xsl:if>` from the OP's code. Without it, the output may consist of rows that only have quotes and nothing else.

Comment: @Dimitre: By your own argument (a solution should be correct only for the given XML input), that `<xsl:if>` should be irrelevant, as it always evaluates to true. Therefore it wasn't missed, just deemed irrelevant.

Comment: @Flynn1179: The OP obviously thinks otherwise, if he is using this code -- I have left the OP's code so that my solution resembles his code as much as possible.

Comment: @Dimitre: That's clearly not true. The predicate I suggested above more closely resembles the OP's code, and you know it. You need to decide which is true; either that predicate is required as given by @Laz, in which case you should specifically use the three elements given as I suggested, or it's not, in which case this answer is missing nothing. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation produces exactly the wanted result without relying on any specific number of `communication` elements**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="vComponent" select="4"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>

 <xsl:template match="communication[string-length() > 0]">
  <xsl:if test="$vComponent = 4">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(
     '&quot;', ../../contactID, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;',
     mediumCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;',
     areaCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;',
     communicationDetails, '&quot;', '&#xa;'
                                 )" />
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided document**:

```
<medicare>
...   
    <person>
        <contactID>5290001890</contactID>
        <communications>
            <communication>
                <mediumCode>T</mediumCode>
                <areaCode>02</areaCode>
                <communicationDetails>92881781</communicationDetails>
            </communication>
            <communication>
                <mediumCode>E</mediumCode>
                <communicationDetails>rabina.smiley@ekit.com</communicationDetails>
            </communication>
            <communication>
                <mediumCode>M</mediumCode>
                <communicationDetails>04290012333</communicationDetails>
            </communication>
        </communications>
    </person>
    <person>
        <contactID>4400139361</contactID>
        <communications>
            <communication>
                <mediumCode>T</mediumCode>
                <areaCode>07</areaCode>
                <communicationDetails>49281771</communicationDetails>
            </communication>
            <communication>
                <mediumCode>E</mediumCode>
                <communicationDetails>suzanne.jones2@optus.com</communicationDetails>
            </communication>
            <communication>
                <mediumCode>M</mediumCode>
                <communicationDetails>0404009266</communicationDetails>
            </communication>
        </communications>
    </person>
    ... 
</medicare>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
"5290001890", "T", "02", "92881781"
"5290001890", "E", "", "rabina.smiley@ekit.com"
"5290001890", "M", "", "04290012333"
"4400139361", "T", "07", "49281771"
"4400139361", "E", "", "suzanne.jones2@optus.com"
"4400139361", "M", "", "0404009266"
```

**Explanation**: Using the fundamental feature of XSLT: *Templates*, *Template matching*, the *XSLT processing model*.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too clear from your question how you would want nodes with extra/missing `communication` elements to be handled, but this answer assumes you want medium codes T, E and M for each contact. If you're actually just wanting anything that's there output, @Treemonkey's answer will do fine based on the inputs given.

Using the index will of course always pick the nth communication element, but you can specify them using a predicate rather than an index. For example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
      '&quot;', contactID, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
      communications/communication[mediumCode='T']/mediumCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
      communications/communication[mediumCode='T']/areaCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
      communications/communication[mediumCode='T']/communicationDetails, '&quot;', '&#xa;', 
      '&quot;', contactID, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
      communications/communication[mediumCode='E']/mediumCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
      communications/communication[mediumCode='E']/areaCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
      communications/communication[mediumCode='E']/communicationDetails, '&quot;', '&#xa;', 
      '&quot;', contactID, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
      communications/communication[mediumCode='M']/mediumCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
      communications/communication[mediumCode='M']/areaCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
      communications/communication[mediumCode='M']/communicationDetails, '&quot;', '&#xa;')" />
```

You can factor out the common elements with a named template with a parameter:

```
<xsl:template name="outputline">
  <xsl:param name="mediumcode" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(
    '&quot;', contactID, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
    communications/communication[mediumCode=$mediumcode]/mediumCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
    communications/communication[mediumCode=$mediumcode]/areaCode, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
    communications/communication[mediumCode=$mediumcode]/communicationDetails, '&quot;', '&#xa;')" />
</xsl:template>
```

and use:

```
<xsl:call-template name="outputline">
  <xsl:with-param name="mediumcode" select="'T'" />
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="outputline">
  <xsl:with-param name="mediumcode" select="'E'" />
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="outputline">
  <xsl:with-param name="mediumcode" select="'M'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

in place of your big `<xsl:value-of>` call.